# Radial tree example from obervablehq migrated to html is rendering centered in the top-left corner

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to implement a radial tree described in this observable notebook: https://observablehq.com/@d3/radial-tidy-tree.

I have tried to implement the code as described in the observable notebook as html but for some reason the center of the radial tree is in the top left corner of the svg.

Here is the jsfiddle version of the implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/syedarehaq/7Lvehf2z/

I am also sharing the code here as a html+js snippet but for some reason it doesn't show the output.

```js
radius = 500;
    tree = d3.tree()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius])
    .separation((a, b) => (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth)
    const data = d3.json("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/d3/d3-hierarchy@master/test/data/flare.json");
    data.then(function(data){
        console.log(data);

      const root = tree(d3.hierarchy(data));
      
      var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      width = 1000;//+svg.attr("width"),
      height = 1000;//+svg.attr("height");
      //g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(60,0)");
      
      svg.append("g")
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .attr("stroke", "#555")
          .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.2)
          .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(root.links())
        .join("path")
          .attr("d", d3.linkRadial()
              .angle(d => d.x)
              .radius(d => d.y));
      
      svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(root.descendants())
        .join("circle")
          .attr("transform", d => `
            rotate(${d.x * 180 / Math.PI - 90})
            translate(${d.y},0)
          `)
          .attr("fill", d => d.children ? "#555" : "#999")
          .attr("r", 2.5);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
          .attr("font-size", 10)
          .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
          .attr("stroke-width", 3)
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(root.descendants())
        .join("text")
          .attr("transform", d => `
            rotate(${d.x * 180 / Math.PI - 90}) 
            translate(${d.y},0) 
            rotate(${d.x >= Math.PI ? 180 : 0})
          `)
          .attr("dy", "0.31em")
          .attr("x", d => d.x < Math.PI === !d.children ? 6 : -6)
          .attr("text-anchor", d => d.x < Math.PI === !d.children ? "start" : "end")
          .text(d => d.data.name)
        .clone(true).lower()
          .attr("stroke", "white");

      //return svg.attr("viewBox", autoBox).node();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
      <svg width="1000" height="1000">
      </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me figure out how to make sure the whole tree is viewable in the SVG area I created?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65611164/7106086) help?

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. It is working now. Should I keep this question? Or should I delete it?

Comment: Glad it was useful. Could close this a duplicate, probably the best option.